# Different output from python function and php conversion

Tags: python, php, output, data-conversion

I try to convert the following python function

```py
def Sous(dist,d) :
    l=len(dist)
    L=[[]]
    for i in range(l) :
        K=[]
        s=sum(dist[i+1:])
        for p in L :
            q=sum(p)
            m=max(d-q-s,0)
            M=min(dist[i],d-q)
            for j in range(m,M+1) :
                K.append(p+[j])
        L=K
    return L
    
print(Sous([3,2,1,0],2))
```

into a PHP function

```php
function sous($dist, $d){
    $l = count($dist);
    $L = [[]];
    foreach(range(0,$l - 1) as $i){
        $K = [];
        $s = array_sum(array_slice($dist, $i+1));
        foreach($L as $p){
            $q = array_sum($p);
            $m = max($d-$q-$s, 0);
            $M = min($dist[$i], $d-$q);
            foreach(range($m, $M+1) as $j){
                $K[] = $p+[$j];
            }
        }
        $L = $K;
    }
    return $L;
}

print_r(sous([3,2,1,0],2));
```

But as I get the right output for python function :

```py
[[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I get a wrong output for the PHP conversion

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )
    ...
```

I can't find where is the problem in the PHP conversion, as I don't really understand the code I try to convert.
Do you have any ideas of where I did wrong ?

Comment: There's no limitation in variable name length, you can use more than 1 character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the translation of the following Python statement:

```
K.append(p+[j])
```

`p+[j]` will create a new list from taking list `p` and appending element `j`, leaving the original list unmodified. Therefore, an equivalent PHP translation would be:

```
$p_copy = $p;
$p_copy[] = $j;
$K[] = $p_copy;
```

I also had to replace:

```
foreach(range($m, $M+1) as $j){
```

with:

```
foreach(range($m, $M) as $j){
```

Putting this all together:

```
<?php

function sous($dist, $d){
    $l = count($dist);
    $L = [[]];
    foreach(range(0,$l - 1) as $i){
        $K = [];
        $s = array_sum(array_slice($dist, $i+1));
        foreach($L as $p){
            $q = array_sum($p);
            $m = max($d-$q-$s, 0);
            $M = min($dist[$i], $d-$q);
            foreach(range($m, $M) as $j){
                $p_copy = $p;
                $p_copy[] = $j;
                $K[] = $p_copy;
            }
        }
        $L = $K;
    }
    return $L;
}

print_r(sous([3,2,1,0], 2));
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you very much you really are my savior !! Thanks again !

Comment: I also forgot to annotate another change I had made. See updated description (the code remains unchanged).